# How to get weechat to stop highlighting my nick in white in chat messages?

Tags: terminal, colors, irc, weechat

I'm using weechat (1.5), and it insists on highlighting mentions of my name in white, which is remarkably hard to see in my "solarized" theme terminals.  While I am easily able to configure many of the colors that weechat uses, I can't find the setting that controls the coloring of mentions in chat messages.

You might think that it's `weechat.color.chat_highlight`, but this controls the color of the *sender* of the message, rather than the color of my nick in the message itself.  Nor is it `weechat.color.chat_nick_self`.

In fact, looking at `/set *color*`, the only things that are set to `white` are:

- weechat.color.chat_buffer
- weechat.color.chat_channel
- weechat.color.chat_prefix_action
- weechat.color.status_name
- trigger.color.regex
- irc.color.topic_new
- relay.color.text_selected

None of these has any impact on my nick color in chat messages. What controls this color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weechat *doesn't* highlight individual words in messages in any way. You probably have a script like `colorize_nicks.py` installed – search settings for `plugin.*` instead.

Comment: Ha, I had forgotten that I had `colorize_nicks.py` floating around! Although...it claims to use nick colors, and `weechat.color.chat_nick_colors` doesn't include "white"...but reinstalling `colorize_nicks.py` seems to have...solved the problem?  At least it's no longer highlighting in white.

Comment: I'm sure the answer was valid at the time.  This changed at some point.  v2.3 default highlights your username.

Comment: @user1902689: It's valid as long as the original question specifically mentions v1.5. However, I cannot reproduce it on v2.3 either – even in highlights, the entire message is still in the same color as before.

Comment: @grawity: You're right, original question does mention v1.5.  I should have been more clear, sorry.  It doesn't highlight my actual username in the message.  If someone else types a message with my username, their username is displayed as yellow text on magenta background, and the window/channel name becomes magenta colored if not the active.  If I type my own username, no special highlighting happens.  No plugins, and only configuration was name/username/server/authentication.  Using v2.3 on Arch (I see they aren't making modifications/configurations from upstream.)

Comment: @user1902689: Yes, **their** username (the 'sender' column) is displayed as yellow text – not yours. That's always been the case in standard Weechat. The plugin that OP had would instead colourize _your_ nickname within the message itself. (Well, it would colourize the nicknames of every person in the channel.) Looks kinda like this: http://aaronfranks.com/img/posts/weechat.jpg https://isene.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/2015-10-25-154055_1599x899_scrot.png